# Remove green crosses to left of lines in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipses java perspective, red circles containing crosses appear to the left of lines with errors; so far so good. However, if an error is corrected, the icon turns green to indicate that there once was an error there but there no longer is one. I can't find a way to stop this from happening, though control+s does remove them. Anyone know how to stop these green crosses appearing? I find them really annoying.

Comment: What version? I don't see those.

Comment: 3.7.0, splash screen says INDIGO.

Comment: Hmm. Me too. Don't see a config for it either, but only tried on Mac so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get rid of them, and actually I just realized, they serve a (potentially) valuable purpose, they indicate that the actual saved file has the compile error still since you have not saved it.

You can make this happen by making a compile error, then saving the file, then fixing it.

If you make a compile error in an unsaved file then when you fix it, the red annotation just goes away.